# Simplifying with restrictions on the whole expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Suppose, for the sake of keeping things as simple as possible, that I have the following equation that I wish to simplify in Mathematica:

$y = x x$

But suppose further that I also have a restriction, not directly on $x$, but on what values $y$ can have. More specifically, let's suppose $y \leq 9$.

What Mathematica expression, if any, will allow me to simplify the above expression for $y$ and get an output that not only simplifies, but also gives me the range of values that $x$ can take to satisfy my restriction on $y$?

So, just to be clear, the function or script I am looking for will output something like the following when dealing with the above:

y = $x^2$ and $-3\leq x\leq3$

Comment: Can you give an example of a simple right hand side $xx$?

Comment: I literally mean x time x. That is just to provide the most basic case.If I see the procedure, I can most likely work on more difficult problems.

Comment: There is nothing to simplify in this your example. Maybe it is much too simple? Could you give a more complex one where some simplification can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`FunctionDomain`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain):

```
FunctionDomain[{x^2, x^2<=9}, x]
```

> -3 <= x <= 3

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Reduce[y == x x && y <= 9, y, Reals]
(* -3 <= x <= 3 && y == x^2 *)
```